# How to identify/authenticate users with socket.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, socket.io

Trying to wrap my head around some logic.

I'm creating a simple turn-based game with Node.js and Socket.io. The idea is that each user 'logs' in via some framework front-end system (quick RubyOnRails scaffold) and then once they are logged in, they can refresh the page and close the browser and they remain logged in as usual until they log out.

I want this functionality of persisted authentication with a web socket so that while 'in-game' users can close their browser and come back at any point and I can relay to other users when a player is disconnected/connected. A player could also join and leave games but could obviously only be in one at a time.

My guess is that upon each page load the new socket.id that a user connects with is needing to be stored in the database inside the users table perhaps? Or is there a simpler way to tie a current user to a socket.id?

Am I going about this the wrong way? I can't seem to find any good examples/documentation similar to what I want. Some code examples or a starter app to push me in the right direction to achieve the basic idea of what I am trying to accomplish would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of tokens for this purpose. A good option would be using JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. **This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed**. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA.
>   - *https://jwt.io*

One possible way to use JWTs in your case goes like this:

1. User logs in
2. A new JWT is issued by server when a successful login happens
3. This JWT is sent to the client and is stored client side (e.g. cookies, local storage, etc.)
4. On every socket connection event, client sends this token to the server for validation
5. Server accepts connection only if the provided token is validated and closes the connection otherwise

The main advantage of using JWTs is that there is no need to store additional data server side because tokens can be validated using cryptographic methods such as digital signatures.

---

More on JWTs: https://jwt.io

Comment: Hey that's pretty interesting I did not know about that technology. Seems like the right direction. I'll have to do more research and see what I can do. Thank you.